# How can I recover erased images on a SanDisk Ultra Plus memory card?

Tags: memory-card, file-recovery

I have a Sandisk UltraPlus 16GB card—used in a Canon Powershot SX30IS—on which nearly every frame has been erased…I don't know how.  I do not format.  I use the card as storage.  I use a card till it's full, then insert a new card.  I do not erase images either.  This just leaves a messy black blank amidst filled frames.  I do not use a computer to view images. My Asus erases a frame if I click reverse.  I view images through the screen on the camera.  I print paper pictures at Walgreen's on their digital-to-print machines.

I know what used to be on the subject card.  I reviewed and made notes. I have printed some of the images.  But when I wanted to print the remaining frames, nearly everything had been erased. The frames remaining are interrupted by erased frames, though they were made on the same two consecutive days.

I can't figure out how they were erased. I seldom go to menu except to correct the date when I change time zones.  My thick fingers often mis-hit buttons on the camera, but none of them should cause erasing.  I've tried to recover with the camera club's WIN Recovery software, with no luck.  What happened and what do I do to retrieve the erased frames?   (I'm emailing SanDisk, but their tech either knows nothing or is hiding something.)

Comment: Recommend closing as unclear, unrelated to photography, and containing demonstrably false claims about OS behavior

Comment: "This just leaves a messy black blank amidst filled frames." "The frames remaining are interrupted by erased frames..." Say WHAT? Have you ever learned anything about how memory controllers work on flash memory cards? Ever heard of 'wear leveling' (which can even apply to the initial writes on a card?

Comment: I _seriously_ doubt "_but their tech either knows nothing or is hiding something_".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows computer- download and install RECUVA.

https://www.wondershare.net/ad/data-recovery/dco.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7vvy-7bv1AIVwhuPCh2uYQXgEAAYASAAEgJNW_D_BwE

Plug the SD card into a usb card reader and run the program.

I have used RECUVA successfully to recover all files from an SD card that was formatted in camera by accident. 
Wishing you success.

Answer (score 0):

There are 'undelete' programs.  But if your camera club has one, and it didn't work, you can try other ones but be prepared to accept the pictures are lost.